# Debian - after update bind9 cannot create log in /var/log/bind

Tags: debian, permissions, bind, debian-buster

Just upgraded debian and named is not starting now. I have 2 log channels configured:

```
    channel "named_log" {
        file "/var/log/bind/named.log" versions 10 size 2m;
        severity dynamic;
        print-category yes;
        print-severity yes;
        print-time yes;
    };

    channel "query_log" {
        file "/var/log/bind/query.log" versions 2 size 100k;
        severity dynamic;
        print-severity yes;
        print-time yes;
    };
```

Everything was working till upgrade. Here's the directory:

```
root@dom:/var/log/bind# ls -la /var/log/bind
total 156
drwxrwsr-x  2 bind bind   4096 Oct 30 17:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 36 root root   4096 Oct 30 15:41 ..
-rw-r-----  1 bind bind 149847 Oct 30 17:45 bind9.log
root@dom:/var/log/bind# id bind
uid=110(bind) gid=118(bind) groups=118(bind)
root@dom:/var/log/bind# ls -lna /var/log/bind
total 156
drwxrwsr-x  2 110 118   4096 Oct 30 17:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 36   0   0   4096 Oct 30 15:41 ..
-rw-r-----  1 110 118 149847 Oct 30 17:45 bind9.log
root@dom:/var/log/bind# named -v
BIND 9.11.5-P4-5.1-Debian (Extended Support Version) <id:998753c>
root@dom:~# ps -eo pid,gid,euid,comm|grep named
 6677   118   110 named
```

But have this:

```
Oct 30 17:04:35 dom named[4997]: configuring command channel from '/etc/bind/rndc.key'
Oct 30 17:04:35 dom named[4997]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
Oct 30 17:04:35 dom named[4997]: isc_stdio_open '/var/log/bind/named.log' failed: permission denied
Oct 30 17:04:35 dom named[4997]: configuring logging: permission denied
Oct 30 17:04:35 dom named[4997]: loading configuration: permission denied
Oct 30 17:04:35 dom named[4997]: exiting (due to fatal error)
```

I temporary enabled login for user bind and can confirm that this user can create and modify files in the /var/log/bind/

Please help

upd: did chmod 777 /var/log/bind - the same error

Comment: Have you tried to touch those files first and then restart the bind service?
:
```sudo touch /var/log/bind/named.log
&& chown bind:bind /var/log/bind/named.log```

Comment: @DmitriyKupch yes, but they're already owned by bind

Comment: can you run:
```ls -l /var/log/bind/named.log
```

Comment: try ```chmod -R 777 /var/log/bind``` to see which user owns those files.

Comment: thanks to @t3ddftw it's solved. Some "apparmor" linups module did that, I'm not too deep in these new things but after adding this dir to its config, everything works as it should

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds as though `bind9` may not be allowed to write to the folder for other reasons.

Check to see if AppArmor is running via `aa-status`.

AppArmor is another mandatory access control mechanism for Linux, comparable to SELinux. In reality, you want it there because it keeps applications from being used maliciously if exploited.

If it is, temporarily disable it to test:

```
sudo systemctl stop apparmor
sudo systemctl disable apparmor
```

If that resolves the issue, then you will need to update the `bind9` profile in AppArmor to allow it access to the log folder.

For reference, AppArmor profiles are stored in `/etc/apparmor.d/`

Comment: I have added this a few minutes ago, you probably didn't reload the question, sorry
```root@dom:~# ps -eo pid,gid,euid,comm|grep named
 6677   118   110 named
```

Comment: And I did chmod 777, the same

Comment: @BbIKTOP - Is AppArmor running? That would be the next thing to check. (`aa-status`)

Comment: have no idea what it is, how to check? did ```root@dom:/etc/firejail# ps -ef|grep -i armor```, got nothing: ```root      9017  7022  0 18:03 pts/6    00:00:00 grep -i armor```

Comment: @BbIKTOP - You probably missed it in my comment -- run: `aa-status`

Comment: Yes, it's running. Thank you!!! wtf is that and how to remove it?

Comment: @BbIKTOP - AppArmor is another mandatory access control mechanism for Linux, comparable to SELinux. In reality, you want it there because it keeps applications from being used maliciously if exploited. Check if temporarily disabling AA fixes your issue by running `sudo systemctl stop apparmor && sudo systemctl disable apparmor`

Comment: thank you so much! Please add this as an answer so I could accept it. Found this *(&^(%^&* and added this dir to its config, everything is working now. linups ok lol ))))

Comment: @BbIKTOP - Updated -- glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: thank you, I'd never find it myself, had no idea it even exists! could you please also add that it's configuration profiles are stored in /etc/apparmor.d and all necessary access rules shall be added there?
I see you already did. Thank you! ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to disable apparmor or reconfigure (expect you really want the logs to go to `/var/log/bind`).

Apparmor in Debian is already configured to allow read+write access to `/var/log/named` (and notes that you should use syslog instead).
See `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named` for more information.

Create the folder as:

```
mkdir -m 775 -p /var/log/named  # can also use mode 770
chown root:bind /var/log/named
```